# Unable to load servlet listener class

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, spring-tool-suite

In advance, I apologize for the lengthy post, but there are a lot of details to this issue:

It started with me receiving the below error when trying to run my Java EE application:

```
 SEVERE: Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR: E:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CAT, module: file:/E:/workspace-sts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CAT/WEB-INF/classes/. Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
```

This seemed to be pointing to my persistance.xml file:

```
 <persistence
    version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
```

So, I changed it to:

```
 <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
```

The error went away but was then replaced with:

```
 SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dally]
 org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet listener class: sdc.cdd.dally.AppListener: sdc.cdd.dally.AppListener
```

Now I'm stuck.  Thanks, in advance, for any help.

BTW, Here's the basic app architecture:

JDK 1.7
STS 3.4
Tomcat 7
Apache Tiles
EclipseLink 2.5.0 - Kepler (JPA)
Maven

I've also included the pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sdc.cdd</groupId>
<artifactId>dally</artifactId>
<name>DALLY</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>9.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles ************************************************************ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
        <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Encryption ************************************************************ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mail ************************************************************ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<organization>
    <name>CSSDRW</name>
    <url>http://www.cssdrw.org/</url>
</organization>
```

Answer (score 0):

full stacktrace will help.

however, your first declaration of `persistence` element is correct, while the second one is deprecated.

and the error seems to be tied to `OpenEJB`. maybe you have it as transient dependency, and is referenced an old version, but this is just a supposition.

another thing is that you are using `javax.inject` and i'm not sure it is usable *standalone* on Tomcat.

you should use a full-featured **application server** (glassfish, jboss, maybe TomEE) instead of an enhanced Tomcat, which is although a **servlet container**, and avoid these compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  I will run the app with jboss and see if it resolves the issue.  If not, I will provide a full stacktrace as requested.

Comment: Well sorry for the long delay in my response but I finally installed JBoss EAP 6.2 and tried re-running the application.  Strangely, JBoss will not start in the SPS and simply provide an endless loop of warning and error messages.  Here's one as an example:

Comment: @NewDawnFades the example is not showing :) update your question and append the new stack trace